# How to jump the cursor to beginning or end of a text selection in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

Is there a way I can jump the cursor to the beginning of the selection so I can then select the opening bracket with shift + leftArrow?

[image]

Comment: just press Left-Arrow to go to the start of the selection

Comment: @rioV8 The OP probably wants to add the `{` to the current selection.

Comment: @Mark I have added a new command to the **Select By** extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command `selectBy.swapActive` from the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) v1.4.0

You can use the Command Palette (`Swap the achor and active (cursor) position of the selection(s)`) or define a key binding.